# MaskedTextBox not get value before delete old value

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I used a MaskedTextBox on my winform and i fill a value from our database. But problem is that when the value is in the MaskedTextBox i can't write anything . But when i delete the value after that i can write in the MaskedTextBox . I set mask on that control is Time 'European Military ' means 24 hrs format . How can i resolve this. i validate it by below code

```
 private void maskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsValidInput)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid time");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't write anything

Sounds like you want this

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox1.Focus();
    maskedTextBox1.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Show please, how do you fill a value from database.